# Get pairwise cosine similarity in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

I need to calculate pairwise `cosine_similarity` for a pandas dataframe and store it back into another dataframe(Pandas).

As of now, I calculate similarity using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise`'s `cosine_similarity`:

`sim = cosine_similarity(df,dense_output=False)`

sample from `sim`:

```
[[1.00000000 8.33333333 ... 8.72871561 8.72871561 8.72871561]
 [8.33333333 1.00000000 ... 7.63762616 7.63762616 7.63762616]]
```

Now I wish to store it back into a Pandas dataframe with this structure:

```
ID  Pair_ID  Sim_Value
1   1        1.00
1   2        8.33
.
.
.
.
2   1        8.33
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the indices then the dataframe

```
i, j = np.indices(sim.shape).reshape(2, -1)
mask = i != j
i = i[mask]
j = j[mask]

pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': df.index[i],
    'Pair_ID': df.index[j],
    'Sim_Value': sim[i, j]
})
```

Comment: your code works flawlessly! Thank you so much. Though your code works perfectly, I am unable to understand the first 2 lines, could you plz explain them?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def create_df(sim):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=sim[0], columns=['Sim_Value'])
    df['Id'] = 1
    for x in range(1,sim.shape[0]):
        tdf = pd.DataFrame(data=sim[x], columns=['Sim_Value'])
        tdf['Id'] = x+1
        df = df.append(tdf)
    df['Pair_ID'] = df.index + 1
    df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    return df
```